# display:none not changing behavior of css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

Here is a simple example of some markup I have:

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="ex1">
<input type="checkbox" name="ex2">
<ul class="reveal">
    <li><a href="#">Hi</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Bye</a></li>
</ul>
```

The checkboxes are used as filters to remove `<li>`s with certain tags. This all works fine. My issue is that when the checkbox is checked and the filter logic runs, it uses a `display:none` to remove the specific `<li>`s but the css I use to format doesn't get applied correctly after the fact. For example, let's say clicking the first checkbox removes the first `<li>` and the 'bye' `<li>` is the only one left. That will work fine, but the border I have defined in the css persists even though the selector shouldn't match it anymore. This is the selector I used:

CSS:

```
#columns .calendar td ul.reveal li + li {
    border-top: 1px dotted #999;
}
```

This style is applied correctly at first, but after the `display:none` is applied and the 'bye' li is the only li left it will still have the dotted border.

I've used the browser developer console to check and this is indeed the only style rule that is being applied to create the border.

I've read something along the lines of `display:none` not repainting the DOM, and to access a variable that forces the browser to repaint (something like $('whatever')[0].offsetHeight) but this does not seem to fix my problem.

Comment: Setting `display` to "none" does not make an element disappear from the DOM. It's still an `<li>` element. If you add a class to it as well as changing `display`, you can have another CSS rule to get rid of the border.

Comment: +1 to @Pointy's answer. ) Actually, I'd place the `display:none' in that class's ruleset as well.

Comment: Agreed with @Pointy. You're on a wild goose chase with repainting the browser. It's behaving as it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### jQuery Based Solution

CSS rules by themselves will not work since the DOM is being manipulated by JavaScript.

What you could do is use JavaScript to identify the first `li` element left in the list.

For example:

```
$('ul.reveal li').filter(':first').addClass('first-child');
```

where the CSS rules are:

```
ul.reveal li {
    border-top: 1px dotted #999;
}
ul.reveal .first-child {
    border-top: none;
}
```

Demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/BXMaB/

The jQuery action picks out the first `li` element in each `ul` list and then applies a CSS rule to know out the top border that appears on all `li` elements by default.

You would need to apply this jQuery action when ever a check box (event) is checked, in addition to binding it to the document load event.

Comment: Instead of adding a class, I just changed the css right after the filter: `$('.reveal li').first().css('borderTop','none');` but, yes, this was eventually what I did.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS selector you have chosen is interested in the structure of the DOM rather than what is and isn't painted. Selector S + S will still apply to S2 even when S1 is being removed, which is why it's still getting a top border.

Given that you are able to manipulate the DOM I would suggest either removing and re-adding the element itself or writing a selector that will respect a class added to S1 (which also applies display:none to it).

For instance:

```
selector:not(.hidden) + selector { [Only works in IE9+] }
```

or

```
selector.active + selector.active { [Works in IE7+] }
```